# Midori: no video but audio on YouTube

Tags: lubuntu, youtube, midori

In addition to Firefox, I frequently use Midori as a browser. Whenever I want to watch a video on YouTube I can only get the audio. But there's no video at all. As far as I know Midori does support HTML5, so theoretically everything should work.

System: Linux/Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, 64 bit

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Try installing `gstreamer1.0-vaapi` package from a terminal as `sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-vaapi` and tell us what happens?

Comment: Hi. That didn't work at all. Midori crashed and shut down. Terminal said:                                                                                                           `(midori4:8720): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 
Trying to dispose element play, but it is in READY instead of the NULL state.
You need to explicitly set elements to the NULL state before
dropping the final reference, to allow them to clean up.
This problem may also be caused by a refcounting bug in the
application or some element.` So I uninstalled it immediately.

Comment: Warning: I cannot find any current Midori version. The PPA was updated 2015-08-30, more than two years ago. For security reasons I would not use a web browser, that is [more than] two years old.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Midori and WebKit should give you what you want via the PPA. Run the following commands to make it work.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webkit-team
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:midori
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude upgrade
```

Otherwise try to start midori via the command line and paste the output here from what it shows when you go to Youtube.

Comment: Hi. O.K., first of all I started midori from the command line. Here is what it tells me: "Vector smash protection is enabled." When shutting down midori those additional lines are added:

Comment: Command line output:   `Vector smash protection is enabled.
libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394`. When shutting down also these messages: `(midori4:2): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_drawable_get_colormap: assertion 'GDK_IS_DRAWABLE (drawable)' failed

(midori4:2): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_window_set_background: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
`

Comment: What kernel version are you on?

Comment: My kernel version: 4.4.0-59-generic x86_64

Comment: Please update the kernel is possible as this could potentially fix the lib error. Otherwise remove the lib completely. It seems to be an error that is corrected in the latest version of midoroi, but it could be kernel dependent as well.

Comment: As far as the latest version is concerned I think I already have that. According to what is told on     http://midori-browser.org/download/ubuntu/     0.5.11-0 is the latest version. The version I have installed is 0.5.11-ds1-2. I´m not quite sure whether that´s the same but it looks like it.

Answer (score 0):

solution found here : 
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=186721

Midori uses gstreamer to decode audio & video. 
so try installing libav for gstreamer :

`sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-libav`

Comment: Hi hoccau. Tnx for the suggestion and the link. I´ll try that as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem on my old PC with Ubuntu 16.04LTS.  Firefox keeps freezing my system when playing Youtube videos after a few minutes.  Cannot find any fix.

I decided to install Midori via Ubuntu Software (old version), however, no video can be displayed in Midori browser even with the suggestions from the above answers.  I removed the old one and then installed a newer version (1.1.4) downloaded from https://packages.astian.org/pool/main/m/midori  (hosted by Astian.org).  Voila!  No problem!  No freezing anymore!

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for letting us know. That´s great news. In the meantime I switched over to falkon. Many greetings.